# Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-processor

Android newbie. My processor is AMD, not Intel, so I can't open the emulator in Android studio.

This answer has the comment: 'You can run the ARM (non Intel) emulator image. From your list, just choose a non Intel emulation.' They don't explain where this can be found. Any ideas? Thanks

[Android Studio emulator and AMD CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765457/android-studio-emulator-and-amd-cpu)

Comment: I just installed the latest version of the Studio and it automatically installed the HAXM emulator which doesn't work with my AMD processor. I uninstalled it but still cannot start the emulator with arm images. Is there a setting somewhere? (Should the be its own question? It seemed relevant here)

Comment: @Bobby King, its been a while since this question answered and would appreciate if you mark my answer as the accepted one if it really helps. Thanks

Answer (score 55):

Alright, first of all, open your Android SDK Manager: Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager, then chose any platform/package you want to download, expand it and select `ARM EABI v7a System Image` or `ARM 64 v8a System Image` then install.

After that, open Android AVD Manager: Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager and create an emulator. You may chose from existing or create your own.

For better results, you may need to restart Android Studio.

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks to [@bjornredemption](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2821633/bjornredemption) for his clue.

As per [Google's latest documentation for Android Emulator v29+](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html) 
Navigate to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager then select the "SDK Tools" tab and tick this option:

**Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors**

Then click Apply to download then use it for your emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I already had both of those tools. I've switched to a device with MIPS as the CPU so I'll see if I can progress with this.

Comment: @BobbyKing King, Glad to help ^_^

Comment: I'm with a Ryzen 7 CPU in 2018 June, and I can only see ARM ABIs offered for the API level 25 and not above. And even if I create a virtual device using that it won't start...

Comment: in 2020 the instructions are muc easier. Just ensure “Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors” is ticked under SDK Tools https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

Comment: TY bjornredemption for the nudge. Enabling in the BIOS and then checking that box in Android Studio removed the need for HAXM when I opened the emulator. THANKS!

Comment: AVD manager still says "Intel HAXM is required [...]" when trying to run on any device

Comment: @Rasmond, you need to be sure that you installed the **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)** from the SDK manager. If you get it installed but you did not run it yet, you may go to: **C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager** then install **intelhaxm-android**.

Comment: Using the family Windows (AMD cpu) computer. And still getting "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. " when trying to install HAXM. I guess Windows 10 home and AMD just isn't supported.

Comment: @blueware that is incorrect for AMD.  I had to run the "silent_install" for gvm.  that fixed it for me.

Comment: As of Android Studio 2022.3.1 the "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" option is missing, and there is a "Android Emulator hypervisor driver (installer)" option. This has not worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

Open Android AVD Manager: Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager and create an emulator:

- Create Virtual Device
- Choose any hardware
- Now in system image you need to click on the "Other Images" tab
- Select an image to install. **IMPORTANT**: Notice that for AMD in the "ABI" column it has to say: **ARM EABI v7a** or **ARM 64 v8a**
- Install it and restart Android Studio

This works for me.

Comment: Oh that's WAY too slow to be at all viable.

Comment: At least could you explain why it´s too slow/not viable and a better way to do it?
Thanks in forehand

Answer (score 8):

I am using [microsoft's Android emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) with Android Studio. I have an AMD FX8350. The ARM one in android studio is terribly slow.

The only issue is that it requires Hyper-V which is not [available on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) windows 10 Home.

Its a really quick emulator and it is free. The best emulator I have used.

Comment: -1 because installing Microsoft's Android Emulator not only has outdated images but it messed up my network adapters and broke VirtualBox.

Answer (score 8):

I have a Ryzen 2600X and I am able to run the emulator without problems. Here are the tweaks I made:

*NOTE: You don't need the beta version of Android Studio or Android Emulator.

1. Go to the MB bios and turn SVM on (CPU Virtualization).
2. In Windows right click Windows Button => Select  "Apps and Features" => "Programs and features" => "Turn Windows Features on and off"
3. In the displayed list select Hyper-V checkbox == Make sure the subfolders are all selected. When prompted to restart, restart the PC.
4. After restart and update instalation screen you are back in Windows and you should be able to run the Emulator.

**Note: I have selected x86_64 and plain x86 images(both API 28) from the x86 Images tab and they work just fine.

***Note: Might also check for Android Licenses if errors pop up, I had an issue because of this while using Flutter, maybe it's related to that.

Comment: Enabling Hyper-V works, but it also breaks Virtualbox/VMware if you use one: https://superuser.com/questions/1208850/why-virtualbox-or-vmware-can-not-run-with-hyper-v-enabled-windows-10

Comment: @icl7126 [VirtualBox 6 can run with Hyper-V](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/hyperv-support.html)

Answer (score 5):

Recent updates enabled computers with AMD processors to run Android Emulator and you don't need to install ARM images anymore. Taken from the Android Developers blog:

> If you have an AMD processor in your computer you need the following
>   setup requirements to be in place:
>
> - AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
> - Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher
> - Android Emulator v27.3.8+
> - x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD)
> - Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
> - Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

The important point is enabling Windows Hypervisor Platform and that's it! I strongly recommend reading the whole blog post:
 https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: Any suggestion regarding ARM images or x86 images for Llinux os...like Ubuntu 18.04 / 16.04, I have AMD Ryzen 5 1600 and 8gb  3000MHZ RAM, with Samsung 240 GB SSD.

Comment: @Bhuro Sorry, I don't have information regarding *nix systems but the blog post explicitly says Windows 10 with April 2018 update. You should probably look to find another workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Since Android Studio 3.2 and Android Emulator 27.3.8 - the android emulator is supported by [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/) and as stated in the official [android developer blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html) - there is mac support (since OS X v10.10 Yosemite) and windows support (since April 2018 Update). You may find further instructions on the developer blog.

In my opinion, the performance is significantly better than all previous workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

My laptop runs on AMD Ryzen 5 and I was facing a similar issue. I tried some of the fixes here but didn't work but eventually, I read hundreds of blogs and came up with a solution. You need the following setup requirements to be in place:

AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher(I run on BETA, However the latest version of Android Studio doesn't need you to install ARM images anymore)
Android Emulator v27.3.8+
x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD)
Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

With all these features in place, I was running Android studio again. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

On mine, I had to install ARM AEBI a7a System Image and Google APIs, and also installed MIPS which was only available for API 15, 16, and 17 (I didn't go below 15.) Took about 12 hours of tinkering, but it works now.

alternatively, you can use Genymotion as an emulator, however will most likely lose design abilities otherwise available with included emulators.

It works now. Pretty slow, but it works. Of course, once you have the emulator started, as long as you don't close it, it will be much faster.

You may need to restart Android studio, and I restarted my entire computer just for good measure.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the Android emulator can be run with Hyper-V instead of Intel HAXM on the Windows 10 1804:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Short version:

- install Windows Hypervisor Platform feature
- Update to Android Emulator 27.2.7 or above
- put WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on into C:\Users\.android\advancedFeatures.ini or start emulator or command line with -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform

Comment: You no longer need the flag for Hyper-V to work. See the latest blog on the Android Emulator:  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 home version with latest android studio (Nov/2019):

1. Enable virtualization from BIOS. If you have a laptop, google how to access the BIOS.
2. Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform". Restart. No need for Hyper-V and Win10 Pro.

Done. Open Android Studio, the annoying warning is gone, emulator starts just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Tuesday, December 3, 2019**

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

Via AMD Hypervisor, we added support for running the emulator on AMD CPUs on Windows:

- With CPU acceleration
- Without requiring Hyper-V
- With speed on par with HAXM

Comment: this is the only solution which worked. DISABLE BOTH HYPER-V and HYPERVISOR PLATFORM !!

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need to do is download extras and tools package from SDK manager and other necessary packages like platform-25 and so on.. , after that open AVD manager and select any emulator you wan't, after that go to "other images" tab and select ARM AEBI a7a System Image and select finish and you are all done hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably heard of Bluestacks, and actually you can run and debug your android apps on the Bluestacks emulator. I think this is the best solution to the slow Android Studios emulator speed. Also next time think about buying an Intel processor instead. Look here for more information: [Connect Bluestacks to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598577/connect-bluestacks-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the AMD processor and had the same issue. To solve this go to control panel-> turn windows features on or off -> check the hyper-V checkbox and click Ok and restart your computer. Now you can create virtual device

Answer (score 0):

Year 2024 Steps for running AVD(Android Virtual Device) with AMD chipset like ryzen for windows.

Make sure you have enabled `Virtualization support` for your AMD CPU (`SVM` is `enabled` in BIOS), then follow the steps below.

NOTE: WSL won't work if you follow these steps.

Steps:

1. In search box type "gpedit" then Goto -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Guard -> Turn on Virtualization Based Security. Now Double click that and "Disable". Apply and Save.
2. In search box, type Turn Windows features on or off, now uncheck Hyper-V and restart system.
3. Open Registry Editor by typing regedit in search box, now Go to HKEYLOCALMACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard. If it doesn't exist, add a new DWORD value named EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity and set it to 0 to disable it (I already had it).
4. Next Go to HKEYLOCALMACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA. If it doesn't exis, add a new DWORD value named LsaCfgFlags and set it to 0 to disable it. (Also had it)
5. Open command prompt (not powershell) as a administrator and type the following commands:

```
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

`Restart your windows` and now it should work when you run `silent_install.bat`, you can find it at `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver`, if its not exist then ensure that you enable it at your `Android Studio > SDK Manage > SDK Tools > install 'Android Emulator hypervisor driver`