# Installing HAXM on Windows 10 for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

Android Studio told me to install HAXM, so I downloaded it and when I went to install, it said `This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology`. After some search, I found that if you uncheck Hyper-V in control panel, all will be well. The problem I'm facing is, it isn't even checked. Is there any other way to fix this issue or does my computer just really not support VT-X?

Comment: You can check Intel's site to see if your CPU supports it or not: http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology If you don't you are stuck with non-hardware accelerated emulator.

Comment: only Intel CPU support HAXM. I have AMD CPU and I faced same problem. You might try to use Android ARM instead HAXM.

Answer (score 7):

This will fix your issue [Develop apps using x86 Android* 4.4 (KitKat) emulator on Intel Developer Zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/develop-apps-using-x86-android-44-kitkat-emulator) see the section

***4. Download and install Intel HAXM***

you will find other emulators intalation also

Answer (score 1):

---

> Make sure Virtualization is enabled in BIOS (advanced Firmware for
>   windows 10)

---

and install manually from 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

after running installation batch file, silent_install.bat of downloaded zip file.

> tns run android  -->Should open up the simulator!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to download latest version of haxm from github url https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
click on the respective release number to get the download option.

For AMD processor see this link.
[Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor)