# I have got an AMD Ryzen CPU and Android emulator doesn't work

Tags: android-emulator, emulation

I have got an AMD Ryzen CPU and Android emulator doesn't work.
It doesn't start the emulator becouse the CPU doesn't support the x86 emulator

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor

Comment: Thanks, i verify when i have time, thanks!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate. None of the options presented in the other thread solve the problem for Ryzen, so the issue seems specific to AMD's latest release. The landscape was intel-only for so long, it might just take a little prodding from the community for Google to build variations that support AMD's underlying technologies. I won't hold my breath, though.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Android Studio's emulator" - the emulator is bundled into the SDK and has nothing to do with the IDE:

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update** - My previous answer is no longer true. Google has added AMD and Hyper-V support into their latest beta. Thanks to [ReverseCold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214180/reversecold) for letting me know. Please see [his answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548499/3107922)

**Update 2** - I had to set this up today. To save some googling, here is the powershell command to enable Hyper-V. Pulled from [Microsoft's Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

```coffee
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Make sure to run powershell as an administrator.

**Update 3** - Turns out there's a difference between **Windows Hypervisor Platform** and **Hyper-V**. You'll need to enable the first one for Android emulation to work. Just click start and type *Turn Windows features on or off* until you see the control panel option of the same name. Then enable the feature from the menu that pops up after clicking that.

---

According to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263360/intels-haxm-equivalent-for-amd-on-windows-os), AMD virtualization for Android is only supported on Linux. If Ryzen becomes hugely popular, maybe they'll write one for Windows, but I won't be holding my breath.

Comment: x86 based VMs didn't start for me on Linux... I tried ARM EABI devices as well, those error out as well. Right now I can only debug a physical device.

Comment: It works now by the way: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Comment: The difference between Windows Hypervisor Platform and Hyper-V pissed me out! Thanks a lot for good advice!

Comment: So can Hyper-V be disabled in the features, or must both Hyper-V and Hypervisor Platform be enabled?

Comment: I think it’s only concerned with Hypervisor Platform. So you should be able to leave Hyper-V disabled if you wish.

Answer (score 12):

The latest beta has support for Ryzen. [Source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)

The following is from the google blog post: If you have an AMD processor in your computer you need the following setup requirements to be in place:

- AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
- Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher - download via Android Studio Preview page
- Android Emulator v27.3.8+ - download via Android Studio SDK Manager
- x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD) - Create AVD
- Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
- Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

Comment: Thank's to @ReverseCold and Update for Ryzen 5 series user's Please use canary stable release. Its out now, Please don't go for beta 3.3 that is currently giving random crashes. Stick to 3.2 stable and you will be fine.

Comment: FWIW I'm on Beta 3.3 and have no issues, but the stable version is definitely a safer bet.

Comment: Still nagging me to install HAXM, won't let me run the damn emulator https://i.imgur.com/O8d6krz.png

- AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
- Android Studio 3.5.3
- Android emulator 29.3.2
- AVDs = x86 and x86_64 Pie (with Play) images (based off Pixel 3a)
- Windows 10 1903 (Sept 2019?)
- Windows Hypervisor Platform enabled

Comment: any luck with this? @twig , I've got a pretty similar setup

Comment: Yep got it working. In Android Studio, go to SDK Manager and tick "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)" and install it. Afterwards, go to `sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver` and run `silent_install.bat` with admin rights

Comment: Once enabled "Windows Hypervisor Platform", remember to enable AMD Virtualization in UEFI. In my Gigabyte Gaming motherboard it is off by default. 
1. Enter UEFI/Bios
2. Choose "Classic Mode" to see all settings. 
3. Enable "M.I.T." -> "Advanced Frequency Settings" -> "Advanced CPU Core Settings" -> "SVM Mode".
No need to extra scripts... Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of ways to get around it:

- [genymotion personal](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) is free but you need to register
- [Visual studio android emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/android/) is also free and is fast. I had issues with it disconnecting on android studio
- Physical device. You will have a hard time trying to see the sqlite database if it isn't rooted.

With the physical device you can download Vysor on play store and install the extension on google chrome. Then you can have the physical device on your monitor.

Comment: None of these worked for me. Genymotion throws a BSOD, visual studio emulator crashes Win10 and bootloops :(

Comment: is that with ryzen -xVacuum?  I am thinking of getting a 1600 for android development.

Comment: Daniel yes, I have Ryzen 5 1600. Unfortunatelly even NoxPlayer (which worked for me yesterday) now throws BSOD's. That's really sad, because compilation and deployment of android applications is super-fast on 6/12 processor. I'm left with wireless USB debugging. None of the emulators work for me, even with AMD-V support. It's still a new CPU, we have to wait.

Comment: @SocketByte That is so unfortunate. You should flag that with the emulator companies. I emailed gennymotion and they confirmed that it should run on a 64bit machine.

Comment: check here the requirements. It is most likely you haven't enabled amd-v in the bios.  
https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Requirements.htm

Comment: nah, I'm not that stupid, AMD-V is enabled, i'm using VirtualBox with Windows 10 image every day which works perfect. A lot of emulators just doesn't work or BSOD's. None of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run the Android emulator on Windows 10 (AMD Ryzen 5 2600) after installing the KB4505903 update.

In my case, only two configuration requirements were needed:

1. Windows 10 May 2019 Update (1903), OS Build 18362.267
2. Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform" ("Платформа низкоуровневой оболочки Windows")

Answer (score 0):

Gennymotion should work for amd users. I emailed them and they said yes it should work.

check [here](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Requirements.htm) to see their specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have AMD CPU somehow it works now.

I don't have x86 installed by HAXM and it still works strange.

Gigabyte CPU/AMD Ryzen 7 ->

MIT Settings -> frequency settings -> advanced -> have SVM enabled

1. Go to windows turn on and off feature 
   -> if you're using windows home, not pro edition, then you need to find "windows Hypervision platform" then check mark it.
2. Create a new AVD virtual device, the newest version may or may not work. You have to do trial and error with different API versions like 25, 26, or newest one.
3. Somehow on SDK Tools, i don't have x86 intel HAXM installed, and it works fine? Does anyone know why it works without intel x86 on my AMD CPU? When i uninstalled it and did everything else again, it finally worked... Strange..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AMD processor in your computer you need the following setup requirements to be in place:

1. AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
2. Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher - download via Android Studio
   Preview page
3. Android Emulator v27.3.8+ - download via Android Studio SDK Manager
4. x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD) - Create AVD
5. Windows 10 with April 2018 Update
6. Enable via Windows Features: "Windows Hypervisor Platform"

**Note:There is Hyper-V features... You should enable Windows Hypervisor Platform not Hyper-V. Windows Hypervisor Platform is at the bottom of features **

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late to answer this but after a few hours of research and verification, here is what I have found.  As of July 2018, if you run AMD Ryzen CPU/APU, you should be able to run Android emulator.  (see [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)).  It does not work on my old AMD Phenom II X6 because the CPU needs to support SSSE3 and SSE4.1 features.  I guess it's time for me to upgrade :)  The toast message I received was "Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSSE3 SSE4.1"

You can follow the instructions in the link above, although I also had to do these in my Android Studio.

1. In the Tools menu > Android SDK > SDK Tools (tab) > Uncheck the option "Intel x86 Emulator Eccelerator (HAXM installer)".
2. Go to Tools menu > AVD Manager > Ceate a new virtual device (choose an image for the x86-64 platform)

Answer (score 0):

### A related question was asked here - [Ryzen 3 with VS android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078511/ryzen-3-with-vs-android-emulator/57184598#57184598) - I've responded there and so thought to cross-link in case others missed it.

This might help you:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cgpaq4/ryzen_android_emulator_whpx_fix_for_windows/

The issue seems to be to do with Windows and has been fixed in the insider builds - you can get it working by following the link above, and without having to become a Windows Insider.

--

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately After turning on **Windows Hypervisor Platform** I can not change the resolution window. It was fixed at non resolution recommended. I do not like at all. Here is my computer's information [image]