# Ryzen 3 with VS Android emulator

Tags: c#, android-emulator, amd-processor

I just can't manage to start them. I have read several threads here. I need more guides to try. I've tried genymotion, Visual Studio.

I want to code in C#. My processor is the Ryzen 3700x.

My error codes genymotion telling me about virtualization, which is on from bios and in Windows. Hyper-V is OFF.

I can manage to start Android emulator with Android 4. Not higher in genymotion. And in VS I can't run my apps at all.

I simply need help to get them up and running, you have new ryzen? What's your settings?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cgpaq4/ryzen_android_emulator_whpx_fix_for_windows/

The issue seems to be to do with Windows and has been fixed in the insider builds - you can get it working by following the link above, and without having to become a Windows Insider.

Hope this helps.