# Computer will not install HAXM, but Hyper-V is not an option within Programs and Features

Tags: android, windows, haxm

Log message "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V."  Typical Android Studio error I've been through before, but this time I cannot access Hyper-V at all. This is a newly built PC.

Windows 10 OS is the free version, which I believe automatically has Hyper-V uninstalled. Therefore, disabling Hyper-V is not an option, nor is it possible with the command line.  I've check in BIOS and no options available.

Answer (score 1):

I was not thinking about my new processor being AMD.  Intel's HAXM obviously will not work, so get into the BIOS and enable SVM (secure virtual machine). Then check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548499/3107922)