# How to install Intel HAXM with Android Studio

Tags: android, hyper-v, haxm

I cannot create a virtual device in Android Studio because I couldn't install an additional package - Intel HAXM. It throws an error:

```
"This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."
```

I found only few links with this issue but it said that I should turn off "Hyper-V" feature in "Windows features" but I have no the such option. My CPU is AMD Ryzen 5. By the way, I am obliged to install the package because it does not allow me to run my app. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31366453/13373270.

Comment: Please be careful tagging questions. You used HAML, in the tag, and in the title and your first paragraph, but this is not a HAML question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAXM is only supported for Intel CPUs. What you can do is enable SVM in your BIOS. After that you will probably be able to enable Hyper-V in windows if you have Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise/Education.
See [Microsoft on HyperV install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v), or
[I have got an AMD Ryzen CPU and Android emulator doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249419/i-have-got-an-amd-ryzen-cpu-and-android-emulator-doesnt-work).
Also make sure you have the latest version of Android Studio

Comment: Thanks! Finally, I fixed the problem thanks to you! For people who will be stuck with this problem, please, open the second link ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249419/i-have-got-an-amd-ryzen-cpu-and-android-emulator-doesnt-work``` and read a two last comments of this post ```https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548499/8741818``` about settings in BIOS and installing package via SDK Manager. It has worked out! Thank you again!

Comment: Anyway, the note about "enabled SVM in BIOS" is correct. I opened my BIOS settings and enabled this feature

Comment: Yep got it working. In Android Studio, go to SDK Manager and tick "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)" and install it. Afterwards, go to sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver and run silent_install.bat with admin rights