# Android Studio Emulator shows only black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[I have added a screenshot of the emulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq62N.png)
I am having an AMD A4 quad core processor with 8 GB of RAM. I installed android studio and Armeabi-v7a API version . The emulator starts but the device does not boots . Even "ANDROID" is also not shown on the emulator screen . Just a black screen and in process it shows " Waiting for device to come online" . Please help me i have also reinstalled emulator from SDK manager.

I also intalled Genymotion plugin. But that was on trial period for some time and now it needs a paid licence. I want to make apps for android gear and test them on emulator. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the emulator configuration? Do you have the GPU feature enabled? How much RAM does your emulator or the AVD have?

Comment: i uploaded the image. I turned on virtualisation already. i gave 3 GB of ram to my device.

Comment: Can you clean the emulator before launch and see if that helps. Also we cannot see the image.

Comment: i have wiped the data of the emulator but it didn't worked...  for image click on the first line of my post...

Comment: Can you reduce the RAM from 3 GB to 512MB and give the VM size as 128MB, also turn off GPU processing and see if that works. Is any other version of the API working and is it possible to try the x86 version.

Comment: i changed Ram to 512...  VM heap to 128 and Internal storage to 2048 MB...  and unchecked Device Frame....  but it didn't helped....

Comment: Is host gpu usage enabled? If so, can it be disabled and tested.

Comment: from where to disable host gpu...???

Comment: Edit the AVD options. There should be one checkbox related to it. If checked, you can uncheck it an try. Also you can trying with HAXM and see if that helps.

Comment: HAXM is for intel procssor only ....  I have AMD processor....

Comment: Right. I missed the AMD portion. Does it load any x86 version of the image?

Comment: no only Armeabi-v7a only...  for x86 it shows error that you need HAXM for running this....

Comment: If you create a new AVD with the above configurations and disabled GPU host does it  give me the same black screen? Also can you try the command... emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd <avd name>

Comment: Check out this link too if this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor

Comment: sir i checked every possible way told in your link but same problem exist....  I also checked on my freind's laptop AMD A6...  and the problem is same....