# (AMD using Windows & Android Studio) ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

This is my experience to the apparent update for users with AMD based computers on July 9, 2018.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

To start, I'm using a Ryzen 1700x and Windows 10 Pro that just finished it's round of windows updates yesterday.

I think I followed everything to the letter but it continues to display that error.

> 10:40 PM  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires
>   hardware acceleration!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0USC.png

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.2.1 and Android Emulator 27.3.10
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpG3I.png

I made sure AMD's virtualization option "SVM Mode" was enabled in BIOS.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/943S7.jpg

I have tried enabling BOTH Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform. I have since disabled Hyper-V since it isn't a requirement, but kept Windows Hypervisor Platform enabled as listed. Either way, it still doesn't work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHkL9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMUMp.png

I have also tried downloading the Canary build 3.3. Still nothing.
I have also tried completely uninstalling my Android Studio, re-downloading and re-installing it. Still nothing.

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you try launching the emulator with software acceleration instead? According to this you should be able to get it working with WHP: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is not mine, It was taken from this question:
[Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor)
Go to this URL and give him appropriate credit to Jorge Valdés.

To solve this problem you have to install the and Android OS for another chip different from the x86 architecture, to do this follow this instruction:

-Create Virtual Device

-Choose any hardware

-Now in system image you need to click on the "Other Images" tab

-Select an image to install. IMPORTANT: Notice that for AMD in the "ABI" column it has to say: ARM EABI v7a or ARM 64 v8a

-Install it and restart Android Studio

I did try and It works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Reinstalled Windows and it worked fine. But the Android emulator is garbage and pretty darn slow on AMD so I ended up returning my AMD parts and upgraded to Intel instead.  Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, That's the best course of action. AMD is pretty good in this new ERA of 14mm or less, but Android Studio and the emulator was create to work the best way on Intel, I can't blame them.