# Missing Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio on Windows but the emulator is missing.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldedah9twfxyp5m/Screenshot%202019-02-28%2014.54.53.png?dl=0

Any ideas? I have been searching for a while but no answers. Please help

Comment: Did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

This is your emulator highlighted in red

[image]

Comment: Yes its not working because my laptop is AMD. I tried going through the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor Still no Luck

Comment: wish you could find a workaround ... you can alternatively use genymotion or BlueStack