# Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)

Tags: android

I use Ryzen 5 2600

BIOS SVM Enabled,
Hyper-V Disabled,
Windows Hypervisor Enabled

http://i.epvpimg.com/y2epfab.jpg

Comment: And what is your question actually?

Comment: I can't create a virtual device on android studio

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor

Comment: Yes, you can. I'm running the same CPU and had the same issue at first but i run Linux and it looks like you're on windows.