# Running android emulator on amd processor

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, amd-processor

I am trying to create android virtual device on AMD processor
My System configuration is

1. AMD RYZEN 5 3500U
2. 64 bit
3. Windows 10 64 bit

I tried to create a android virtual machine by

1. Start Android Studio
2. Tool bar > Clicked on the Android Virtual Device Icon > Create Virtual Machine> Choose a device definition > Pixel 2 > Select a system image>Other Images> Nougat armeabi v7a

It created a virtual Machine with android Nougat installed on it. But It lags very severly and even my hello world app crashed every time I tried to run it on my machine.

I read the following questions before asking here

[Run Android studio emulator on AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366453/run-android-studio-emulator-on-amd-processor)

The problem is that I created armeabi v7 image on my system but It lags serevly. and even my Hello world app crashed every time I tried to create it.

Note: While I was selecting a image for my virtual machine. One the right hand side Android studio suggested that I should select x86 system image for x86 host. Does this means I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Use x86 image as other answers have suggested, try to avoid answers dating pre-ryzen release as they'll be irrelevant.

Comment: See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Comment: @Pawel DO you mean that I should select x86 image in the list of system images. I tried to do that but even the download of image crashed every time. It says check the IDE log for details? Do you use amd ryzen or have you used it in the past?

Comment: I have the same cpu. Pick x86 images only.