# i can't run my app in my real phone

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

After generating `apk` with android studio, I took my `apk` file in my phone, then I installed it but when I tried to open it, I got an error (check out pic, this error occurs after gettomg apk from android studio):

> "unfortunately app Has stopped"
>   [image: Error When i tired to install my app after i exported apk by eclipse]

When I tried export `apk` by eclipse, I got file `apk` with small size **270kb**, and when I moved it in my phone I could not install it I get error

[image: Size of apk file after exported apk by eclipse]

**Help Me Please . . . .**

Comment: Happened to me in the past that antivirus did not give it run.But I do not think that's the case.

Comment: Is the apk file version you created a suitable device?

Comment: Yeah i did but i get error :(

Comment: Did you try on another device?

Comment: yeah i did with many devices i got the same error

Comment: So the problem is with the file.

Comment: You will need to look at the code that created the apk file.

Comment: put your `androidmanifest.xml` code

Comment: You need to use adb (the android debugging bridge) and show us the resulting logcat log where the error occurs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598577/connect-bluestacks-to-android-studio without logcat, we're blind.

Comment: Some other problems your phone is having (although, that may not be the problem). Your phone doesn't have enough free internal memory, usually you need to have at least 30% of free memory. Also your external sdcard, or your sim card, is missing. I'm not sure which. Again, that's probably not the problem, but you should take care of that problem anyway because your phone will lock up more frequently if you're running low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the Instant Run in Android studio and clean and rebuild your project. Run it on any emulator and then install the generated apk in your real device. Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank you for comment 
but i can't Turn off the Instant Run 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/SBCsC.png

Comment: Uncheck the 1st option of Enable Instant Run and try again. :)