# Cannot create AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm installing Android Studio for the first time, and when I'm trying to create a virtual device, it shows the following error:

`An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details.`

But I can't find idea.log.

I searched everywhere for the file, but it is not present. I meet all the system requirements as well. I tried re-installing  Android Studio, but it is still not working.

Comment: You can check this thread to find the location of idea.log: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19784877/8192914

Comment: Installation of AVD may fail due to multiple reasons. Please add the exact log that says why it failed to your question after you've found it.

Comment: First, check that your system is enabled with Hyper-V (Virtualization). If not, enable it from BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information in your question right now to understand why AVD creation isn't successful. So I can't help you now. However, you can consider the following alternative solution.

Instead of using Android Studio's virtual device, you can use BlueStacks emulator to run your application. Of course Android Studio's emulators should be your first choice. Use BlueStacks only if you fail to install AVD.

After installing BlueStacks, go to `settings -> advanced` and enable android debug bridge. You'll find a text in the same window that says "Connect android at 127.0.0.1:5555". The ip address along with the port number is important for the next step.

Find the location of adb.exe file. To find it, `open android studio -> go to settings -> search SDK`. You'll find the path of the SDK folder. Go to the SDK folder. In the SDK folder, there is a folder named platform-tools. This folder will contain the adb.exe file.

From the command line, go to the location of platform-tools folder. Alternatively, you can right click on platform-tools folder and select 'open terminal here'. Then run the command `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555`. Note, it is the same address that you found in the settings of BlueStacks.

After successfully executing the command, you shall be able to detect the emulator in android studio.

You can find more details here: [Connect Bluestacks to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24598577/8192914)